# How to make child div wrap before its flexbox parent container wraps?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to have a the last div in the row wrap within itself before it gets wrapped to the next line.

```
<div class="flexcontainer">

        <div class="col1">this is text</div>
        <div class="col2">this is text</div>
        <div class="col3">
          <div class="contents m1">This is some other text</div>
          <div class="contents m2">This is some other text</div>
          <div class="contents m3">This is some other text</div>
        </div>

</div>
```

```
.flexcontainer{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.col3{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.contents{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Here's the code of what im working on.
[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/pkxvLoz2/)

Here's the [simplified code](https://jsfiddle.net/2tmeswj5/) like I posted

I'm not exactly sure what I did before. I was able to create a 3 column flex container where the last child would wrap within itself before it's container wraps, but I can't seem to find the solution on how i did it previously.

Comment: i want the contents to be displayed as a row

Comment: actually what u want to do? do want to have 3 div in the same row?

Comment: I want the last div  to have its contents wrap before the flex container wraps the last div..

Comment: basically I want the last div to have as many divs in the row it is able for the dynamic width it has.

Comment: but instead what is happening is the whole column gets wrapped before its contents are wrapped

Comment: nevermind still not solved.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is what you are expecting -"makes child div wrap before its flexbox container wraps.".

use `flex :shrink | wrap | basis` property and `flex-wrap` property to wrap the div contents.

```css
.flexcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.flexcontainer>div {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.col3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: red;
}

.contents {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="col1">This is text</div>
  <div class="col2">this is text >> IT WILL BREAK AFTER HERE | | | </div>
  <div class="col3">
    <div class="contents m1">This is some other text</div>
    <div class="contents m2">This is some other text</div>
    <div class="contents m3">This is some other text</div>
    <div class="contents m3">This is some other text</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: this is close. the last div is doing what it is supposed to, but the whole container is not. the main container should also wrap its div contents

Comment: plz post expected output image @VchCvhHvc

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2tmeswj5/1/ this is how I expect the content to interact. I would use this fix, but in order to use this fix each column must have a specified width. This causes a issue because I do not want to specify a width for each column because it would render it nonresponsive.

Comment: It solves it just like auto-fit on a grid layout but the thing is you need to specify a width. Which is problematic if the width is meant to be dynamic

Comment: @VchCvhHvc I think in the grid also u need to specify the minimum width - repeat(auto-fit, minmax(186px, 1fr));

Comment: if u don't want to specify the width then u can set flex:1 1 0; now check my answer @VchCvhHvc I have removed the width.

Answer (score -2):

I think the `.col3` className is duplicate in the container element.

If you remove it, it should make the content 3 columns.

Comment: not a duplicate.. it has those properties because I want the divs inside .col3 to show as a row, and not automatically break to next line.